# Checks on timestamp with Postgres and Knex

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am attempting to add a check on two `timestamp` columns using Knex with a Postgres backend. For some reason, Postgres is rejecting the check, even though I have an identical check with `date` columns types. The syntax is identical otherwise, although the `date` columns are `notNull` while the `timestamp` columns are, so maybe that's it?

This works on a different table:

```
t.date('startDate').notNull();
t.date('endDate').notNull();
t.check('?? < ??', ['startDate', 'endDate']);
```

This does not:

```
// Existing column
t.timestamp('resolvedAt');

// New migration
t.timestamp('fulfilledAt');
t.check('?? <= ??', ['resolvedAt', 'fulfilledAt'], 'fulfilledAt_check');
```

Fails with:

```
migration failed with error: alter table "Order" add constraint
fulfilledAt_check check($1$2 <= $3$4) - syntax error at or near "$2"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try without the `'fulfilledAt_check'`?

Comment: Looks like a version of this issue [Can't add a constraint in existing table](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/5344). From the looks of it the parameterized values are not being converted to the field names in the migration script. So instead of  `check(resolvedAt <=  fulfilledAt)` you are getting `check($1$2 <= $3$4)` and the syntax error.

Comment: @Pompedup yes, it didn't make a difference